# UIPageViewController not recognizing swipe when added as a subview

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

What's more neither the delegate or dataSource methods are being called.

setupPageView is called from the viewDidLoad of the viewController that owns the view the pageViewContoller is embedded within.

Is there something I'm overlooking here?

```
func setupPageView() {
    pageView = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: [.interPageSpacing : 9])
    pageView.dataSource = self
    pageView.delegate = self
    pageView.setViewControllers([graphViews[0]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.addChild(pageView)
    let bounds = pageViewContainer.bounds
    pageView.view.frame = bounds
    pageViewContainer.addSubview(pageView.view)
    pageView.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

Changing the pages manually works fine using the code below:

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    var direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection = .forward
    let newIndex = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    if newIndex == index {
        return
    }
    if newIndex < index {
        direction = .reverse
    }
    index = newIndex
    pageView.setViewControllers([graphViews[index]], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

extension GraphPageView: UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

    if completed {
        //update index
        guard let currentVC = pageViewController.viewControllers?[0] else { fatalError("No Current VC")}
        guard let currentIndex = graphViews.index(of: currentVC) else { fatalError("No VC found") }
        self.index = currentIndex
    }
}
```

}

extension GraphPageView: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    //
    if index == 0 { //@ begining of stack
        return nil
    } else {
        return graphViews[index - 1]
    }
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    //
    if index == graphViews.count { //@ end of stack
        return nil
    } else {
        return graphViews[index + 1]
    }
}
```

Comment: where are your datasource and delegate

Comment: Is it embedded in a splitViewController? In that case add: `splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = false`. Make sure to add this before setting the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try allowing interaction by the following line

```
pageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

This helps when a view is encapsulated in other views but needs to capture touches

Comment: pageView.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true doesn't cause the dataSource and delegates to be called or swipe to work

Comment: I missed the first line where you say the delegate and dataSource are not called. Where do you call setupPageView from?

Comment: setupPageView is called from the viewDidLoad of the viewController that owns the view the pageViewContoller is embedded within.

Answer (score 0):

You should change index inside `viewControllerBefore` & `viewControllerAfter`  to reflect current index so when you scroll get the the next / previous index respectively , have a look to this [pager](https://github.com/ShKhan9/pager)

Comment: Maybe...but the dataSource code isn't executing nor is the delegate code. This is not my first PageVC

Comment: Can you check the demo it does the same thing added as a child also